# Remote access to Database PostgreSql on NAS Synology DS216jv

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have a Synology NAS DS216j in my LAN and I am running a postgreSQL database on it.

I am try to find a way to connect and run my database from a computer outside my LAN so I can use it and update it. In order to do that I had to forward the port 5432 (postgres) and WebDav (5005) of my router to the NAS.

The port Postgresql (5432) and WebDav (5005 )is open on my public IP. The port Postgresql (5432) and WebDav (5005 )is open on the NAS.

From the remote host:
I am able to see the database file (in LibreOffice Base), on the NAS if I connect with quickconnect or WebDav (in windows I installed the program: NetDrive).

I am able to connect to the database structure with PgAdminIII.
but I am not able to Launch/Open the database.
When I get prompt the user and password I just get this error saying:

> The connection to the data source "NAS" could not be established.
>   Couldnt establish database connection to ´sdbc:postgresql:postgresql://192.168.0.20:5432/dbname´ could not connect to the serve: Connection timed out (0x0000274c/10060). Is the server running on host 192.168.0.20 and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432?

I wonder why I am able to connect with PgAdminIII but not able to open the LibreOffice Base from WebDav.

----UPDATE ----

[image]

Comment: The error message suggests that you are using the (private) IP address 192.168.0.20, which will not work from outside your LAN.  Try using your PUBLIC IP address when connecting from remote locations (ie outside your LAN).  Also, I'd use a ':' in front of the port number (not a '/') eg when using the LibreOffice's Database Wizard, step 2 (connection settings) the datasource URL should probably look something like: postgresql://YOURPUBLICIPADDRESSHERE:5432/dbname .

Comment: Hi, I am using Netdrive with Webadav to connect from outside my LAN. I do use my PUBLIC IP to Connect to the NAS. I can see the LibreofficeFiles and I can open the Database file, but when I try to open a form of the database I get a request of user and password (which I know), but  then i get the error above mentioned. And yes I used the ":", my mistake, will update my post now.

Comment: It seems that you are using Netdrive to access the LibreOffice file sitting on your NAS box.  Is this the case?
Connection "diagram": Remote Machine (using NetDrive) <-> Router <-> Nas Box (Libre Office file located here).
That would explain why PgAdmin works REMOTELY (using your public IP address), but Libre Office doesn't.  NetDrive seems to be built for transferring files (ie it does not handle traffic to/from the Postgresql server adequately).

Comment: As a next step I suggest that you try the following: with the computer connected to your LAN (no need to leave the house :-), create a LibreOffice test file on the machine you intend to use REMOTELY.  Use your OUTSIDE IP address.  Then try to connect.  Let us know what happens. Use the "Test" button when stepping through the "Wizard".  If you get an error message "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host ...", then you are on the right track.

Comment: Get rid of the "FATAL ..." message (see previous comment) by adding an entry into pg_hba.conf, in the # IPv4 local connections section: 
host all all YOURPUBLICIPADDRESS/32 md5
  Save the conf file, the restart the postgres server (service).  Now the "Test Connection" should be successful.

Comment: Hi @stefan , thank you for all the tips. Yes your diagram is correct. The reason I want to run the db postgreSQL on the NAS is because I want all the hosts of the LAN be able to use it (and that works). Also I want to be able to connect from outside my LAN from any PC so that I can update the DB when I am not home. I dont have your advice clear enough. Where should this test libreoffice file be created? In one of the hosts inside the LAN or in the computer I am using to connect from remote(outside my LAN)?

Comment: (you men: the machine i am intending to use remotely which is my NAS or the machine I use to connect to the NAS from Remote?)

Comment: When saying/writing "remote" machine I mean a computer that is NOT on your LAN.  (Machines connected to the LAN are "local" machines.)  Now take a step back and consider: a networked computer (whether it's connected to your LAN or not) should be able to communicate with machines that have a PUBLIC IP address, right?  Your router has a public address.  Thus, a "local" machine (ie on your LAN) should be able to connect to your router's public IP address. - - That's why it does not matter where the "test" file/machine is located - because it will always try to get to your router's public address.

Comment: Your current .odb file, however, has a PRIVATE (local) IP address in its settings.  When you load this file into a remote machine (ie when the client machine is connected to somebody else's LAN!), it will "try" to find your Postgres server ON THAT LAN (ie sombody else's LAN) -> then you get the error message. (Because your Postgres server runs on YOUR LAN).  The fact that you have opened a port on the router does NOT help in this situation, because the router will only forward the traffic for the Postgres server when it hits its outside network interface (with your PUBLIC) address.

Comment: Ok so, when I connect from a remote machine into my LAN, I can rich the NAS and open the libreoffice Base file, but that postgres is ment to run only in local. I will then have to change some settings in the LibreofficeBase File so that I can put my public IP address there.

Comment: My suggested test setup:
Remote Machine (LibreOffice test file here) <-> Router port 5432 <-> NAS.  The LO test file points to the router's public IP address.  This should also work when the "Remote" machine is (still) connected to your LAN e.g. if you have a laptop that you are using on your LAN and - sometimes - for accessing your LAN remotely.

Comment: I am a bit confused, and I might have been not clear, can you see if the picture I update my question with is more understandable? The remote computer can obiously use teamviewer to connect to one of the host of the LAN so that can handle the database but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: This (your picture) is exactly the situation I'd imagined.  Whatever I wrote was with this kind of scenario in mind.  Remember that your PUBLIC IP address is tied to your router, though.

Comment: I assume that the "big box" in your drawing represents your LAN.  All networked devices are in the same address pool: 192.168.0.0/24 (guessing that you use a 24 bit subnet mask).  Look at your REMOTE HOST.  We don't know its IP address!  It must have an IP address, though - otherwise it cannot connect to the "internet".

Comment: Suppose the following: You visit a friend, who lives a couple of miles away.  You bring your laptop and use their WLAN.  Your friend's router uses the same private address pool as yours: 192.168.0.0/24.  What would you expect when trying to connect to a database server with the IP address 192.168.0.20?  (If your friend has a database server running/listening on that very address, you would get to THEIR server.)